# Django unicode issue with datetime in Jython with SQLite JDBC

Tags: django, sqlite, jdbc, unicode, jython

I recently started a Django project using Jython. I created a virtualenv and successfully created a Django 1.8.6 project, using a JDBC file for SQLite (sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2).

I could create a superuser with `jython manage.py createsuperuser`, loaded the admin URL and logged in successfully. I even could create another user from the admin. The problems begin when I tried to edit a user. The server cannot render the template of the detailed instance of the user Model.

I have not installed any external apps, nor created an app in the project. I am using django.contrib.auth for the User models and the Django admin default interface.

The initial error I get when I load the `/admin/auth/user/1/` is `'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'`:

```
AttributeError at /admin/auth/user/1/

'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/1/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:

'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

Exception Location: /home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py in is_aware, line 337
Python Executable: /home/dmunoz/jsnmp/bin/jython
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:

['/home/dmunoz/snmp/webswitcher',
 '/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django_jython-1.8.0b3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages',
 '/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib',
 '/home/dmunoz/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib',
 '__classpath__',
 '__pyclasspath__/']

Server time: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 12:31:09 -0300

Error during template rendering

In template /home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
```

Because of this, I tried setting `USE_TZ = False` in the settings.py file. Then, I got `'unicode' object has no attribute 'date'`:

```
AttributeError at /admin/auth/user/1/

'unicode' object has no attribute 'date'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/1/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:

'unicode' object has no attribute 'date'

Exception Location: /home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in decompress, line 888
Python Executable: /home/dmunoz/jsnmp/bin/jython
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:

['/home/dmunoz/snmp/webswitcher',
 '/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django_jython-1.8.0b3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages',
 '/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib',
 '/home/dmunoz/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib',
 '__classpath__',
 '__pyclasspath__/']

Server time: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 12:28:18 -0300

Error during template rendering

In template /home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
```

The final error I have got is when I tried to dump the data from auth.User model with `jython manage.py dumpdata auth.User --indent=4 --traceback`:

```
[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py", line 159, in handle
    serializers.serialize(format, get_objects(), indent=indent,
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 61, in serialize
    self.handle_field(obj, field)
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 55, in handle_field
    self._current[field.name] = field.value_to_string(obj)
  File "/home/dmunoz/jsnmp/Lib/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1487, in value_to_string
    return '' if val is None else val.isoformat()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isoformat'
```

Python version: 2.7.0, 
Jython version: 2.7.0, 
Django version: 1.8.6, 
django-jython version: 1.8.0b3, 
SQLITE JDBC version: 3.8.11.2

---

**EDIT:**

I created a Django App, with a single and simple model:

```
from django.db import models

class PMV(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateField()
```

I created an instance in the admin web page, with Date = today. When I tried to edit it, I got this:

[image: Screenshot from admin, model with DateField]

After this, I added a `models.DateTimeField()` to the PMV model, created an instance and tried to edit it. I got the `'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'` error again.

Comment: Looks like you have a string (`unicode`) object where a `datetime.datetime` object is expected.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do? Because this error occurs with the default Django admin models. Should I try with another JDBC, override the auth.User model, or just try a different approach?

Comment: It does smell like some kind of bug in the data access layer, probably related to the way SQLite doesn't actually have a native datetime storage type.

Comment: I would start by trying other versions of Django, maybe even a development snapshot.  That could tell if you if there is an oversight on your end, or if there is indeed a bug that was was introduced into Django at a particular moment in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be readily explained:

1. sqlite3 [lacks explicit datetime](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) support as 'bobince' points out in the [comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637913/django-unicode-issue-with-datetime-in-jython-with-sqlite-jdbc#comment55077398_33637913)
2. django.db.backends.sqlite3 works around this via storing as text in ISO-8601 format
3. but this is not part of JDBC support, which expects real datetime support

Note there is an [outstanding bug](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1682864) to add complete sqlite3 support to Jython. I just adjusted the milestone for that bug to 2.7.2 (could be later). Such support is something we have wanted to do for a while, although it's a bit complicated because it's not just a question of using JDBC.

For the time being, this likely means you would to either do your own workaround (don't know scope); or switch to a database like MySQL or Apache Derby (small footprint like sqlite3, but with support for datetimes).